# WinApi: How do you get the handle to a main window that is running in the background?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

Typically I can `FindWindow()` using the class name to find other instances to be able to send a message to another process (of the same app).  However, if the application started from the task scheduler in the background, `FindWindow()` fails to find it (I presume `EnumWindows()` would too).

**the question is:** how do you get the handle to a Main Window that is running in the background?

It's something that would rarely be used and only for an instant So setting up shared data areas seems like overkill.  A shared mutex already exists (if the owners handle could be used?).

It's just to send a message to it so it can log its status since you can't see anything when it's running in the background.

TIA!!

Comment: GetProcessWindowStation(), EnumDesktops(), EnumDesktopWindows().  To what degree session 0 isolation is going to ruin that is not so obvious, at a minimum you need to elevate.

Comment: WinApi does not have a main window concept. A process can have 0, 1 or several visible top-level windows.

Comment: In this case it can assume one main window/dialog.   for now I've used a global event handle, but the background task can't create a window on the desktop, it can communicate with an app via global namespace but then that app has to be elevated or it can't create in the global namespace, I really don't want to elevate that app, but the other one is always elevated, I think I'll have to work within the realm of the elevated apps will end up having to setup shared memory in the global space.

Comment: Windows offers several ways to implement [interprocess communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications).